# Best practices for displaying a webpage in different languages

Tags: wordpress, internationalization, nginx, locale

I would like to deploy a webpage in different languages (German and English). As a backend solution I would use Wordpress running on a nginx/PHP/MySQL stack on Linux.

From various posts here I think that looking at the browser locale (the `ACCEPT-LANGUAGE` field in HTTP request) is a good first try for setting the correct language. Of course the user will be able to override this and this choice will be stored in a cookie.

So my questions is:

*How would one implement that in wordpress? Would one have to deploy two separate wordpress installations one for each language or is there some plugin for it which I have not found yet.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the plugin "[WPML"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/).  Pretty sure that will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**@GorillaPatch,**

See [this question on WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/707/710#710) on how to add language support to your WordPress theme using the .mo and .po files.